# Create viewport for map loaded from tiled Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, viewport

I have created a loader for tiled in the JSON format for my JavaScript game. The game is based on a 2048 x 1280 map and my canvas size is 704 x 608.

So my predicament is how would i create a viewport/camera when the player approaches the edge of the canvas ,so that the map will move?

In my situation, it is a little more difficult, because im not using a standard 2D array like most of the tutorials, so it is confusing me very much.

The code for loading my map is like so:

```
function Level (){

var data;
this.tileset = null;
var returned;
var t = this;


this.load = function(name){
   $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "maps/" + name + ".json",
        dataType: 'JSON',
       async: false,
       success: function(success){
          returned = loadTileset(success);
       }
    });

    return returned;
};

function loadTileset(json){
    data = json;
    Level.tileset = $("<img />", { src: json.tilesets[0].image })[0]
    Level.tileset.onload = done = true;

    if(done){
        return data;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

this.draw_layer = function(layer){
    if (layer.type !== "tilelayer" || !layer.opacity) { return; }
//        if (layer.properties && layer.properties.collision) {
//            return;
//        }
    var size = data.tilewidth;
    layer.data.forEach(function(tile_idx, i) {
        if (!tile_idx) { return; }
        var img_x, img_y, s_x, s_y,
            tile = data.tilesets[0];
        tile_idx--;
        img_x = (tile_idx % (tile.imagewidth / size)) * size;
        img_y = ~~(tile_idx / (tile.imagewidth / size)) * size;
        s_x = (i % layer.width) * size;
        s_y = ~~(i / layer.width) * size;
        ctx.drawImage(Level.tileset, img_x, img_y, size, size,
            s_x, s_y, size, size);
    });
};


this.collisionLayer = function(layer){
        var row = [];
        t.solids = [];
        layer.data.forEach(function(idx, i) {
            var s_x,s_y,
                size = 32;
            s_x = (i % layer.width) * size;
            s_y = ~~(i / layer.width) * size;

            if (i % layer.width === 0 && i) {
                t.solids.push(row);
                row = [];

            }
            row.push([idx,s_x,s_y]);

        });
        t.solids.push(row);
};

return t.solids;
}
```

And this Level class is called from my main javascript file like this:

```
layer = scene.load("level_"+level);
                layer = $.isArray(layer) ? layer : layer.layers;

                layer.forEach(function(layer){
                    if(layer.name == "v.bottom" && layer.type == "tilelayer"){
                        b_layer = layer;
                    }
                    else if(layer.type == "tilelayer" && !layer.properties){
                        t_layer.push(layer);
                    }
                    else if (layer.type == "objectgroup"){
                            $.each(layer.objects, function(i, value){
                                coll_layer.push([value.x,value.y,value.width,value.height,"dialogue"]);
                            });
                    }
                });
```

And then scene.draw_layer() is called from my update function lower in my main javascript function.

My map holds different layers and you can see in the code above there is and if statement determining where the layer is the bottom layer, top layer or and object layer and storing it in the specific array. This is just so the player is shown between layers.

So to clarify, for my game, how would i create a view port/camera according to my map loader?

Also do i move the map or the player?

And should i keep the player centered? if the player is centered then what happens when the edge of the map is visible?

Here is a live version of the game so you can see how it works etc:

[LIVE DEMO](http://upbeatevents.co.uk/dis)

Use guest as the username and password

Thankyou very much

**UPDATE**
I have made a small progression i believe but with big consequences. I have tried implementing a viewport from a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kmHZt/10/) on one of the questions on here, its designed to work with a 2D array, but thought id give it a go.

and the result can be found here:

[Updated link](http://upbeatevents.co.uk/dis)

If anyone could have a look to see where im going wrong it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: getting **"Error establishing a database connection"** error when i navidate to your demo link

Comment: Sorry mate wrong link, Ive just updated it

Comment: these are my findings:1.You have to move the User by few distance(not centered exactly) and also the map too.now this has to be done before the player reaches any corner for better visualization,watch diablo II on google.i hopw that should give you some idea

Comment: how do you mean few distance? Ive read in a lot of places that it should only be the map moving not the player?

Comment: In your game, i Saw that the user has reached the corner of the canvas, i meant you can move the map and user accordingly just few pixels before that.its all about better visualization, and live gaming exp.I meant in real picture it should seem like both the map and as well as the user has moved,its logical that u have to move just the map by few pixels based on the movement of the player

Comment: Dont try moving the by large margin, as it would not give any good user exp.move the map by single step based on the player movement.

Comment: Ok, youve totally lost me now! sorry haha

Comment: :) no issues, gaming things are always tough to understand, anyway one advice i can give you is that you can check any mouse movement games like warcraft or diablo, to understand how you can achieve the same. Happy coding :)

Comment: Does anyone else have any input for this at all? I really need to solve this quick to move on thankyou